# We could not refresh the credential for the account

Tags: visual-studio

I am not able to "Sign in" to Visual Studio 2019 (enterprise). I am getting below message[image]

Not sure what is the issue here. I start getting this issue once I configured my laptop on domain account.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was interesting to fix. I tried almost all workaround out there on internet. None of them fixed the issue.
Repair, reinstall, cleaning temp, .Identity, etc. weapons were useless :).
This is what worked for me -

> I had to install windows updates and remove the user profile.

This is what my IT told me.
Hope someone can verify this. I pray to God no one come to this issue.

Comment: please post the steps to remove user profile. I am facing same issue.